# Well-definedness of Euler-Poincare characteristic of a module

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology

Suppose that $M$ is an $R$-module, where $R$ is a commutative, unital ring, and that $M$ has two finite free resolutions:

$$ \ldots 0\rightarrow F_n \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow M,$$
and
$$ \ldots 0\rightarrow G_m \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow G_0 \rightarrow M.$$

How do we show that $ \sum_{i=0}^n (−1)^i \text{rank}(F_i) = \sum_{j=0}^n (−1)^m \text{rank}(G_j)$?

If $R$ was a field one could use the rank-nullity theorem. I suppose it has something to do with the splitting lemma in the general case but I am really stuck.

Comment: Hint: there is a homotopy equivalence between $F$ and $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way to prove it.

Step 1: It is enough to prove the statement for $R$ a local ring because localizing at a maximal ideal is exact and doesn't alter the ranks. From now on we assume R is local so that projective modules are free.

Step 2: It's true when $M$ is free because then any finite resolution divides into a bunch of split short exact sequences of free modules and we should just get $\text{rank}M$ for the Euler char.

Step 3: Pick a shortest possible free resolution $F^\bullet$ of $M$ and consider the short exact sequence $0\to N\to F^0\to M\to 0$. Then $N$ has a shorter free resolution than $M$ and by induction we can assume that the Euler char. of $N$ and $F^0$ is independent of the free resolutions. Now for any free resolution $G^\bullet\to M$ we can pick free resolutions $G_N^\bullet$ for $N$ and $G_F^\bullet$ for $F^0$ so that they fit into a short exact sequence of complexes $G_N^\bullet\to G_F^\bullet\to G^\bullet$ (this is horseshoe lemma). Now one can use this short exact sequence to show that the Euler char. of $M$ is the Euler char. of $F$ minus the Euler char. of $N$ and hence independent of the resolution $G^\bullet$.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds quite interesting. But the book I am reading must have had a different argument in mind, unfortunately, so other answers are still very welcome. .

Comment: You're welcome=) Btw if $R$ is an integral domain we can reduce to the case of a field by localizing at the prime ideal $(0)$.